# cordova not available in browser

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic3

I just start learning ionic framework and trying to implement Facebook login using firebase. I am running this application in browser and I have following codes which is giving me "cordova_not_available" error. Can anybody help me learn what is wrong with my attempt.

Thank you.

Inside app.module.js

```
import {Facebook} from '@ionic-native/facebook';
import firebase from 'firebase';

export const firebaseConfig = {
    ....
    ....
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

Inside home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {Facebook} from '@ionic-native/facebook';
import firebase from 'firebase';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public facebook: Facebook) {

    }
    fblogin() {
        var me = this;
        me.facebook.login(['email']).then(res=>{
            const fc = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(res.authResponse.accessToken);
            firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(fc).then(fs => {
                alert("Firebase sec");
            }).catch(ferr => {
                alert("error");
            })
        }).catch(err=>{
            console.log("JSON.stringify(err)");
        })
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

Cordova plugins are not available when running the app in the browser with ionic serve. In order to be able to use the Cordova plugins, you'd need to run the app on a simulator / real device.

**UPDATE**

> I need to run app on android and browser

The only way I can think of, is to use the platform information to check if the app is running on a mobile device (`this.platform.is('cordova')`) and if it is, use Cordova plugins. If it is not, you'll need to do things just like you'll do them when creating a web site, like using the REST api from Firebase (and thus, not using Cordova plugins)

> Where should I check this platform?

Right before calling any Cordova plugin related method. So it could be in your services, or in the `app.component.ts` file. It's just to decide if you need to use a method based on a Cordova plugin, or if you need to execute a method that uses a web service.

Comment: so if I have to run using browser, what should I do. I am trying to implement facebook login using firebase and ionic framework. Can you suggest me any tutorial that I can follow

Comment: Do you mean during development, or you app is going to be used in the browser?

Comment: The only way I can think of, is to use the `platform` information to check if the app is running on a mobile device (`this.platform.is('cordova')`) and if it is, use Cordova plugins. If it is not, you'll need to do things just like you'll do them when creating a web site, like using the REST api from Firebase (and thus, not using Cordova plugins).

Comment: where should I check this platform?

Comment: Right before calling any cordova plugin method. So it could be in your services, or in the `app.component.ts` file. It's just to decide if you need to use a method based on a cordova plugin, or if you need to execute a method that uses a web service

Answer (score 3):

Add the browser plugin
-- `ionic cordova plugin add browser`

then run your project by the following command
`ionic cordova run browser` instead of `ionic serve`

Answer (score 2):

Cordova is avilable in browser for that we need to install xampp srver and ripple emulator and then it will work

Steps to run:

1) Install Xampp follow the procedure

2) Install Ripple emulator and run app in localhost and then it will work

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to achieve the same and [sebaferreras](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3915438/sebaferreras) is right. You need different approaches for mobile version and for browser version. Something like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Facebook, FacebookLoginResponse } from '@ionic-native/facebook/ngx';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
// ...

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

    constructor(
        private fb: Facebook,
        private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
        private platform: Platform
    ) { }

    /**
     * If it has Cordova support (Android, iOS), it returns true, otherwise false (usually browser).
     */
    private isCordova(): boolean {
        return this.platform.is('cordova');
    }

    doFacebookLogin(): Promise<any> {
        if (this.isCordova()) {
            return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
                this.fb.login(['email']).then((response: FacebookLoginResponse) => {
                    const credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(response.authResponse.accessToken);
                    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithCredential(credential).then((res) => {
                        resolve(res);
                    });
                }).catch((error) => {
                    reject(error);
                });
            });
        } else {
            return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
                let provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
                this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider).then(res => {
                    resolve(res);
                }, err => {
                    console.error(err);
                    reject(err);
                });
            });
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```